# How to find the lowest difference between two numbers from the given list in python using loops?

Tags: python, loops, nested-loops

I can't figure out how to make the random number in the list subtract each other than find the smallest difference. I can't use def() , sorted(), return or any import as they are not in the lesson yet.

```
def findMinDiff(arr, n):
    arr = sorted(arr)
    diff = 10**20
    for i in range(n-1):
        if arr[i+1] - arr[i] < diff:
            diff = arr[i+1] - arr[i]
    return diff
arr = [4, 1, 2, 9, 7, 100, 5, 0, 99, 100]
n = len(arr)
print("The lowest different between two numbers is " + str(findMinDiff(arr, n)))
```

Sample Output:
The lowest different between two numbers is 0.

Comment: of consecutive numbers or of all combinations?

Comment: What would be the correct result from the list shown in your question and why?

Comment: Tip: `n` should be defined in the body of the function not given as a parameter. What is `diff` and why is it so big?

Comment: `import` [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) will change your life

Answer (score 1):

To find the smallest difference between any two adjacent values in the list you could do this:

```
arr = [4, 1, 2, 9, 7, 100, 5, 0, 99, 100]

smallest_diff = float('inf')

for x, y in zip(arr, arr[1:]):
    if (diff := abs(x-y)) < smallest_diff:
        smallest_diff = diff
print(smallest_diff)
```

**Output:**

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested-loops as you mentioned in tags

```
min_diff = abs( arr[0] - arr[1] )
for i in range(len(arr)-1):
    for j in range(i+1,len(arr)):
        diff = abs( arr[i] - arr[j] )
        if diff < min_diff:
            min_diff = diff
```

Thanks to @stuart

Comment: You don't need math.abs because *abs()* is a Python built-in function